# Double quotes, commas and escapes in Data factory

Tags: csv, quotes, azure-data-factory

I have .xlsx source file sinking into a .csv file.

The dataset settings are as followed

[image]

This is causing a break in my .csv file

[image]

The text in the memo column looks like this before the break

> blah blah "foo foo foo"  bar. blah / foo

should the double quotes be escaping my memo column and creating a row?
I thought that it would need to have a comma?

Changing the setting to "no quotes characters" would cause an issue as this column also contains commas.

I've tried changing the escape to double quotes but get the new row still with a quote in.

I'm also trying to think of my process going forward that utilizing a similar dataset for this file in two more places. can I fix this at the ingestion stage or will all datasets need to change?

What should I be setting this to?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Source Data Set `sample1.xlsx` and the configuration :

[image]

Sink Dataset `outputcsv2.csv` and the configuration :

[image]

Please make sure you select `Flatten hierarchy` under `Copy Behavior` under `sink` - in Copy Activity Settings:

[image]

Here is the `outputcsv2.csv` under the my Storage account after the Copy Activity runs successfully:

[image]